# Jquery: check if variable is defined after keyup() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, onkeyup

Am creating register form with `jquery` function `keyup()`,
for example if  input is correct I assign it to a txtuname variable,then  I press register button and  I need to know that all form variables are correct and defined.Code below is not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">      
$("document").ready(function() {
  $("#txtuname").keyup(function() {
    if ($("#txtuname").val().length < 6) {
      jQuery("label[for='txtuname']").text("user name is too short");
    }
    if ($("#txtuname").val().length >= 6) {
      var txtuname = $("#txtuname").val();
      jQuery("label[for='txtuname']").text("");
    }
  });
  $("#submitRegistration").click(function() {
    if (typeof txtuname == 'defined') {
      alert("defined");
    }
    if (typeof txtuname == 'undefined') {
      alert("undefined");
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `typeof txtuname =='defined'` change to `typeof txtuname = "string"`

Comment: `typeof txtuname =='undefined'` change to `undefined === txtuname `

Comment: place `txtuname` after `script` tag

Answer (score 1):

Modified code. Main point of this code is that `txtuname` should be visible in both scopes of `keyup` event listner and `click` listner. So if there are more lements, create ***Validation object*** and just check whether all the values was set and correct. And yes, use or `$` or `jQuery` in your code.

```
$("document").ready(function(){

    var txtuname = null;

    $("#txtuname").keyup(function(){
        if($("#txtuname").val().length<6){
            jQuery("label[for='txtuname']").text("user name is too short");
        }

        if($("#txtuname").val().length>=6){
            txtuname=$("#txtuname").val();
            jQuery("label[for='txtuname']").text("");
        }
    });

    $("#submitRegistration").click(function(){
        if( txtuname == null || txtuname.length < 6)  ){
            alert("incorrect");
        }
        else{
            alert("correct");
        }

    });
});
```

---

**Updated** check of variable using comment of @Rhumborl , thx

Comment: I would just set it to `null` on initialization and when invalid, then just check `if(txtuname === null)`, rather than duplicating logic

Answer (score 1):

Replace code with below condition -

```
if( typeof txtuname !== 'undefined' && txtuname.length >= 6)  ){
  //proceed further
}else{
   alert('Please correct entries.');
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would put the validation logic in a function and call that, you can update this with your specific requirements and only do it once:

```
function isValidName(field) {
  var myName = field.val().trim();
  // some of this is redundant but just to show possibilities
  var isValid = myName.length && myName.length >= 6 && myName && undefined !== myName && myName != " ";
  var myLabel = $("label[for='" + field.attr('id') + "']");
  if (isValid) {
    myLabel.text("");
  } else {
    myLabel.text("user name is too short");
  }
  return isValid;
}
$("document").ready(function() {
  $("#txtuname").keyup(function() {
    isValidName($(this));
  });
  $("#submitRegistration").click(function() {
    var nameIsValid = isValidName($("#txtuname"));
    if (nameIsValid) {
      alert("valid");
    } else {
      alert("undefined or invalid");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I think there are problem  with this `undefined !== myName`, because everytime it gives me an answer user name is too short, if I delete `undefined !== myName` from conditions, then it works.

Comment: That should have the same effect as `(typeof myName !== "undefined")` unless undefined as been altered manually which is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You are using $ as well as jQuery window.jQuery object in your code. Do not use both at time , you can check by both

```
jQuery("document").ready(function() { jQuery("#txtuname").keyup(function(){ if(jQuery("#txtuname").val().length<6){

    jQuery("label[for='txtuname']").text("user name is too short");
}

if(jQuery("#txtuname").val().length>=6){

var txtuname=jQuery("#txtuname").val();
jQuery("label[for='txtuname']").text("");

}
});

jQuery("#submitRegistration").click(function(){

if(typeof txtuname =='defined'){
    alert("defined");
}
if(typeof txtuname =='undefined'){
    alert("undefined");
}

});
});
```

Or use by replace jQuery by $ sign. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way too......

```
$("document").ready(function(){

var txtuname;

$("#txtuname").keyup(function(){
    if($("#txtuname").val().length<6){
        jQuery("label[for='txtuname']").text("user name is too short");
    }

    if($("#txtuname").val().length>=6){
        txtuname=$("#txtuname").val();
        jQuery("label[for='txtuname']").text("");
    }
});

$("#submitRegistration").click(function(){
    if(typeof txtuname=="undefined"){
        alert("undefined");
    }
    else{
        alert("defined");
    }
});
});
```